# Batch request by Facebook graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, batch-processing

I want all the form ids which are associated with ad ids of my facebook business account.
The problem is hitting graph api one by one for all ad ids and fetching form ids is slow and results in limit exceed error as there are around 700+ ad ids.
Is there a way that I provide all the ad ids at once or my facebook busineess account id and get all form ids associated with it ?

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
        $formIds = (Common::makeCurlReq($val['ad_id'] . '/leads', 'form_id', '', 0, 10000));
        $formsIdsArr = array();
        foreach ($formIds['data'] as $a => $d) {
            array_push($formsIdsArr, $d['form_id']);
        }

        $queryString = "";
        $uniqueFormIds = array_unique($formsIdsArr);
        foreach ($uniqueFormIds as $data) {
            $queryString .= "('$val[ad_id]', '$data'),";
        }

        $obj->mapFormId(rtrim($queryString, ','));
    }
```

Comment: batch requests will not prevent you from hitting api limits, the same limits still apply. for example, if you do 50 calls in a batch, it will still count as 50 api calls. it is only faster. anyway, please add your current code.

Comment: @luschn I have added the code